# UIButton re-enabled after disable from different method

Tags: uibutton, reset, ibaction

I want to re-enable a UIButton in Xcode after it has been disabled. I disabled the button by calling the IBAction when the button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)A0:(UIButton *)sender{
UIButton *enableButton = (UIButton *)sender;
enableButton.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)B0:(UIButton *)sender{
UIButton *enableButton = (UIButton *)sender;
enableButton.enabled = NO;
}

// Lots more buttons

-(Void) reset {

//re-enable all buttons

}
```

I wish to be able to re-enable all the buttons when the reset method is called

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to manipulate user interface objects like buttons, create IBOutlet properties in the view controller that manages the objects and link the objects to those properties. That done, you'll be able to use the properties to enable the button(s) like this:

```
-(void) reset {
    //re-enable all buttons
    self.buttonA.enabled = YES;
    self.buttonB.enabled = YES;
    //...and so on
}
```

If you don't want to use outlets for some reason (e.g. you have a large number of buttons and don't often need a reference to each individual button), you might also consider using tags. Every view has an integer `tag` property which you can set to any value you like. Tags can be set in the .xib/storyboard editor. Once you've set a view's tag, you can easily find it in your view hierarchy using the `-viewWithTag:` method. If you use tags, your `-reset` method would look something like:

```
-(void) reset {
    //re-enable all buttons
    [[self.view viewWithTag:kTagForButtonA] setEnabled:YES];
    [[self.view viewWithTag:kTagForButtonB] setEnabled:YES];
    //...and so on
}
```

where `kTagForButtonA` and `kTagForButtonB` are integer constants that match the tags set on individual buttons. If you have lots of buttons with consecutive tags, you could obviously also use a `for` loop to set each one in turn.

Also, it looks like all your actions do exactly the same thing -- each one disables the button that sent the message. If that's the case, you can use a single action for all your buttons:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Is their an easy way to create the IBOutlets along side the actions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "along side", but if you mean declaring them just before or after the code that defines the action, no. You should declare your outlet properties in the class declaration (the `@interface` section in your .h file). If you don't want to use outlets, tags are another good way to find UI elements. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Im having a problem in implementing this. I have linked the button to the header file, so now has 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *A0Button;

but when I have 
self.A0Button.enebaled = NO; in the implemention file is says property A0Button not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many `UIButton` objects and it's not feasible to manually enable each `UIButton` object by name, you can try this:

```
-(void)reset
{
    for(UIView *currentView in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([currentView  isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [currentView setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

this will get all `UIButton` objects you have in `self.view` and `setEnabled:YES` to them (*whether they're already enabled or not*)